# Go Modules - how to reference a branch in GitHub

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm using [Coreos OIDC library](https://github.com/coreos/go-oidc) and would like to know how to reference (in `go.mod` file) a branch, since they don't develop under `master` but use `v2` instead.

I tried `github.com/coreos/go-oidc@v2` but I get:

```
go: github.com/coreos/go-oidc@v2@v2.0.0+incompatible: invalid github.com/ import path "github.com/coreos/go-oidc@v2"
go: error loading module requirements
```

Comment: Did you try `go get github.com/coreos/go-oidc@v2` in your project directory? For me it seems that it added this dependency correctly.

Comment: that works well but it is not reflected in `go.mod` file.
and when I navigate to the lib code it seems to be the old master version

Comment: It wired that's is not reflected, because when I did that it automaticaly added me all dependencies. Here is my files which were generated after `go get` https://gist.github.com/t-tomalak/a55d9483a2ba876c9f11611456f77c8e

Comment: do you have a reference to `SkipIssuerCheck` at `verify.go`? That would mean you have `v2`. otherwise you're in `master`

Comment: https://github.com/coreos/go-oidc/blob/v2/verify.go#L243

Comment: It's for sure pointed to newer version I can copy examples from v2 branch and their compile properly. Where are you checking code reference? It should be in `GOPATH/pkg/mod/github.com/coreos/go-oidc@v2.0.0+incompatible` at least I had it there

Comment: Could you share your `go.mod` and `go.sum` file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lsoares/6d1bc0957c646f7c2d3bdf875ca16039
the way the software is behaving it's like the old. and through IDE navigation I get to the old as well

Comment: Did you try to run `go mod tidy && go mod verify && go mod download` ?

Comment: it doesn't change.. but it might be IDE stuff if it works in yours - you get v2 branch. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase `import path` in the error message suggests that somewhere in your code you have written something like:

```golang
import "github.com/coreos/go-oidc@v2"
```

But the import path of a Go package does not include its version: only the entries in the `go.mod` and `go.sum` files do.

So instead you should write:

```golang
import "github.com/coreos/go-oidc"
```

and update your `go.mod` and `go.sum` files by running

```
go get -d github.com/coreos/go-oidc@v2
```

That should result in an entry in your `go.mod` file like:

```
require github.com/coreos/go-oidc v2.0.0+incompatible
```